# Domain of unbounded selfadjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A:D(A)\subset H \to H$ be a selfadjoint unbounded operator on a complex Hilbertspace $H$.  Let $\lambda_0\in I$ for some open interval $I$. Define $g(\lambda):=(\lambda_0-\lambda)^{-1}(1-\chi_{I}(\lambda)) $ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $h(\lambda):=g(\lambda)(\lambda_0-\lambda)=1-\chi_I(\lambda)$. Accoridng to spectral theorem $$h(A)=g(A)(\lambda_0-A)=Id-E(I)$$ is defined on $D(h(A))$. ($E$ is spectral measure).

Here comes my confusion. 
Looking at left-hand side I expect $h(A)$ to be defined **at most** on $D(A)$, since it's a composition of operators. But I claim $h(A)$ is defined everywhere since 
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|h(\lambda)|^2d \Vert E(\lambda)u \Vert^2=\int_\mathbb{R}|1-\chi_I(\lambda)|^2 d\Vert E(\lambda)u \Vert^2 \leq2^2\Vert u \Vert^2 < \infty, \quad u \in H.$$

So where is the mistake?

Comment: You didn't define $E,h(A)$, how does your spectral measure relate to $A$ (and which part makes it unbounded)

Comment: No mistake. $h$ is bounded, so you have $D(h(A))=H$ and $h(A)$ is bounded, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @MarsPlastic but doesn't $g(A)(\lambda_0-A)u$ make sense only for $u\in D(A)$, since $D(\lambda_0-A)=D(A)$ ? How can it be defined on whole space if $u$ must pass through $\lambda_0-A$ first?

Comment: You mean $g(\lambda) = (\lambda-\lambda_0)(1-\chi_I(\lambda)$ right? Now you have some troubles with the functional calculus. The formula $h(A) = g(A)(\lambda_0-A)$ is true on the domain of the right hand side. However the domain of the left hand side is strictly larger. In general you have
$f_2(A)\cdot f_1(A) =(f_1\cdot  f_2)(A)$ when restricted to the domain of the left-hand side, but it looks like the domain of the right-hand side is strictly larger? This is because the domain of the formula on the left-hand side is here smaller than it should be.

Comment: @s.harp thank you! I think your comment perfectly qualifies as the answer.

Comment: I believe the closure of $f_2(A)\cdot f_1(A)$ is $(f_1\cdot f_2)(A)$, but I'm not sure if its actually true. I'll think about it in a bit and if I can show it I'll write it in an answer.